# Debezium Connector filter "partly" working

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium

We have a debezium connector that works without any errors. Two filtering conditions are applied and one of them works as intended but the other one seems to have no effect. These are the important parts of the config:

```
"connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
"transforms.filter.topic.regex": "topicname",
"database.connection.adapter": "logminer",
"transforms": "filter",
"schema.include.list": "xxxx",
"transforms.filter.type": "io.debezium.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.filter.language": "jsr223.groovy",
"tombstones.on.delete": "false",
"transforms.filter.condition": "value.op == \"c\" && value.after.QUEUELOCATIONTYPE == 5",
"table.include.list": "xxxxxx",
"skipped.operations": "u,d,r",
"snapshot.mode": "initial",
"topics": "xxxxxxx"
```

As you see, we want to get records which have op as "c" and "QUEUELOCATIONTYPE" as 5. In kafka topic all the records have the op field as "c". But the second condition does not work. There are records with QUEUELOCATIONTYPE as 2,3,4 etc.
A sample record is given below.

```
"payload": {
    "before": null,
    "after": {
      "EVENTOBJECTID": "749dc9ea-a7aa-44c2-9af7-10574769c7db",
      "QUEUECODE": "STDQSTDBKP",
      "STATE": 6,
      "RECORDDATE": 1638964344000,
      "RECORDREQUESTOBJECTID": "32b7f617-60e8-4020-98b0-66f288433031",
      "QUEUELOCATIONTYPE": 4,
      "RETRYCOUNT": 0,
      "RECORDCHANNELCODE": null,
      "MESSAGEBROKERSERVERID": 1
        },
    "op": "c",
      "ts_ms": 1638953572392,
      "transaction": null
  }
}
```

What may be the problem? Even though I wasn't thinking it was going to work, I've tried switching the placement of conditions. There are no error codes, connector is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it. I was using a pre-created config. While reading documentations, I've seen that `"skipped.operations": "u,d,r"` is not an Oracle configuration. It was in the MySQL documentation. So, I deleted it and changed the connector name (cached data can cause problems so often). Looks like it's working now.